# Why can I write $|\nabla u|=\sup_{\tau \in S^{n-1}} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau}(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Why can I write the module of the gradient in this way?

$$|\nabla u|=\sup_{\tau \in S^{n-1}} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau}(x),$$

where $u:\Omega\subset \mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a $C^\infty$ function, $S^{n-1}=\partial \mathbb{B}(O,1)$, and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau}(x)$ is the directional derivative.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau} = (\tau \cdot \nabla)u = \tau \cdot (\nabla u). $$
Then we have, by Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$ \lvert \tau \cdot (\nabla u) \rvert \leqslant \lvert \tau \rvert \lvert \nabla u \rvert = \lvert \nabla u \rvert, $$
since $\tau \in S^{n-1}$, with equality precisely when $\tau$ is proportional to $\nabla u$ (clearly there are 2 such $\tau$ on the unit sphere, and one gives $+\lvert \nabla u \rvert$, the other $-\lvert \nabla u \rvert$).